# Dynamically Adding Key/Val Pairs in angular formly

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I am using `ngx-formly` to build UI dynamically based on JSON. I am currently having some problems implementing the add/delete functionality for a `key/val`

Since all my keys/values are dynamically added to the JSON, I need to find the `key` based on the index and remove it. I am able to see the keys on the `this.field.parent` property

The buttons I added to add/delete are based on an extended type. Not sure if this is a good approach or is a better way to do this?

[image]

[Stackblitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-key-val-pairs)